# Instruments / UI Automation is selecting the wrong target to run

Tags: ios, xcode, ui-automation

I have an iPhone app that I am writing and it has 2 targets for two different builds of the app target 'A' and 'B'.
I selected to build target A and when I build on the device or the simulator it properly builds and runs target 'A'.
When in instruments (`UI Automation`) I select target 'A' but it builds and runs the app as target 'B'.

Any idea why this is happening?
I selected the proper app but the other one is running instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is controlled by your project's scheme. Make sure each target has it's own scheme, and edit the "Profile" portion of the scheme appropriately for each target.